# what does start and end refer to in the disk managment on linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, debian, disk-management

I have started learning basic IT and Disk management on Linux for a program I am writing. I started with the parted tool and when creating a disk it requires start and end values for creating partitions and I don't understand what start and end refer to. (as you can see below there are start and End columns they are what I refer to).

```
test@test:~$ sudo parted -l
[sudo] password for test: 
Model: ATA VBOX HARDDISK (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 21.5GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  538MB   537MB   primary   fat32        boot
 2      539MB   21.5GB  20.9GB  extended
 5      539MB   21.5GB  20.9GB  logical   ext4


Model: DiskModel
Disk /dev/sdb: 4005MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      65.5kB  4005MB  4004MB  primary  NTFS         boot
```

All help is much appreciated, thank you in advance, Yovel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### What does start and end refer to?

First you need some basic understanding of partitions:

> Partitioning is the process of dividing a storage device into local
> sections, called partitions, which help organize multiple filesystems
> and their associated operating systems.
>
> A storage device presents itself as a sequence of bytes, numbered
> starting from zero and increasing until the maximum capacity of the
> device is reached. Bytes are normally read and written a sector at a
> time, rather than individually. Each sector contains a fixed number of
> bytes, with the number determined by the device.
>
> ```
> +------------------------------------------------------------+
> |            storage device with no partitions               |
> +------------------------------------------------------------+
> 0 start                                                    end
> ```
>
> In order to store multiple filesystems, a storage device can be
> divided up in to multiple partitions. Each partition can be thought of
> as an area which contains a real filesystem inside of it. To show
> where these partitions are on the device a small table is written at
> the start, shown as PT in the diagram below. This table is called a
> partition table, or disklabel, and also stores the type of each
> partition and some flags.
>
> ```
> +--+---------------+----------------+------------------------+
> |PT|  Partition 1  |  Partition 2   |  Partition 3           |
> +--+---------------+----------------+------------------------+
> 0 start                                                    end
> ```

Now you have to create a partion:

> Command: `mkpart [part-type name fs-type] start end`
>
> Creates a new partition, without creating a new file system on that
> partition. This is useful for creating partitions for file systems (or
> LVM, etc.) that Parted doesn’t support. You may specify a file system
> type, to set the appropriate partition code in the partition table for
> the new partition. fs-type is required for data partitions (i.e.,
> non-extended partitions). start and end are the offset from the
> beginning of the disk, that is, the “distance” from the start of the
> disk.

Example:

> The following creates a logical partition that will contain an ext2
> file system. The partition will start at the beginning of the disk,
> and end 692.1 megabytes into the disk.
>
> ```
> (parted) mkpart logical 0.0 692.1
> ```
>
> Now, we will show how to partition a low-end flash device (“low-end”,
> as of 2011/2012). For such devices, you should use 4MiB-aligned
> partitions2. This command creates a tiny place-holder partition at the
> beginning, and then uses all remaining space to create the partition
> you’ll actually use:
>
> ```
> $ parted -s /dev/sdX -- mklabel msdos \
>     mkpart primary fat32 64s 4MiB \
>     mkpart primary fat32 4MiB -1s
> ```
>
> Note the use of ‘--’, to prevent the following ‘-1s’ last-sector
> indicator from being interpreted as an invalid command-line option.
> The above creates two empty partitions. The first is unaligned and
> tiny, with length less than 4MiB. The second partition starts
> precisely at the 4MiB mark and extends to the end of the device.
>
> The next step is typically to create a file system in the second
> partition:
>
> ```
> $ mkfs.vfat /dev/sdX2
> ```

Source [Parted User’s Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/parted/manual/parted.html#Using-Parted)